# Java equals super and sub class

Tags: java, inheritance, equals, equality, instanceof

I have the following two very simple classes:

```
   public class A {

    private int a;

    public A(int a)
    {
    this.a=a;
    }
    public int getA(){
        return a;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (!(o instanceof A))
            return false;
        A other = (A) o;
        return a == other.a;
    }
}
```

And its subclass:

```
public class B extends A{
    private int b;
    public B(int a, int b)
    {
        super(a);
        this.b = b;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (!(o instanceof B))
            return false;
        B other = (B) o;
        return super.getA() == other.getA() && b == other.b;
    }
}
```

This might seem right initially, but in the following case it violates the symmetry principle of the general contract of the specification for Object, which states:
"It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)
The failing case is the following:

```
public class EqualsTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A(1);
        B b = new B(1,2);
        System.out.println(a.equals(b));
        System.out.println(b.equals(a));
    }

}
```

The first returns true, while the second returns false.
One solution that might seem right would be to use `getClass()` instead of `instanceof`. However, this would not be acceptable in cases where we look for B in collections. For example:

```
Set<A> set = new HashSet<A>();
set.add(new A(1));
```

The method `set.contains(new B(1,2));` would return false. This example as is, might not be ideal to be logically visualized but imagine if A was a Vehicle class and B was a Car class, with field a being the number of wheels and field b being the number of doors. When we call the contains method we essentially ask: "Does our set contain a 4-wheel vehicle?" The answer should be yes since it does contain it, regardless of whether it's a car and the number of doors it has. 
The solution Joshua Block suggests in Effective Java 2nd Ed pg 40 is not to have B inherit from A and have an instance of A as a field in B instead:

```
public class B {
    private A a;
    private int b;
    public B(int a, int b)
    {
        this.a = new A(a);
        this.b = b;
    }

    public A getAsA()
    {
        return A;
    }  
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (!(o instanceof B))
            return false;
        B other = (B) o;
        return a.getA() == other.getA() && b == other.b;
    }
}
```

However, does this mean that we lose the power to use inheritance in a great number of cases where it is needed? That is, when we have classes with extra properties that need to extend the more general ones to reuse the code and just add their extra more specific properties.

Comment: You are using composition instead of inheritance. In your case, do you think Liskov substitution principle applies for B if you decide to go for inheritance?

Comment: You can avoid this problem if you identify your objects based on one unique ID property that exists in the base class. Then you don't have to override the equals() implementation of the base class. When you compare two vehicles, you could compare the number of doors and the number of wheels and a 1000 other properties, or you can simply compare the vehice IDs. Which option makes more sense to you?

Comment: @Eran It does make sense to use unique ids to compare objects but this is not sufficient in every case. Imagine that you have a Car and you make a deep copy of it once the user enters a specific part of your application. Then you let the user decide whether he/she wants to mutate that original car object. Then upon exiting this part of the application you want to check whether the user actually changed the object or not. So you compare it with the original copy. Their ids will obviously be the same, but their other properties might differ.

Comment: This is a well-known problem with inheritance from concrete classes, and the Java date classes are a notorious example. The rule to make classes either abstract or (effectively) final has some merit.

Comment: @SMA,  Liskov's substitution principle is valid if the equals method in A uses instanceof instead of getClass(). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the collection issues, I would find it highly unintuitive and confusing for `b.equals(a)` to return `true`.

If you want to consider `a` and `b` equal in some context, then implement explicitly the equality logic for that context.

1) For example, to use `A`s and `B`s in a `HashSet` by relying on equality logic of `A`, implement an [adapter](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter) that will contain `A` and implement the `equals` method:

```
class MyAdapter {
   private final A a;

   MyAdapter(A a) {
      this.a = a;
   }

   public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof MyAdapter)) {
            return false;
        }
        MyAdapter other = (MyAdapter) o;
        return a.getA() == other.a.getA();
    }
}
```

Then simply add adapter objects to the set:

```
Set<MyAdapter> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(new MyAdapter(new A(1)));
```

Then `set.contains(new MyAdapter(new B(1,2)));` returns `true`.

Of course, you can write a wrapper class and pass it `A`s (and `B`s) directly, hiding `MyAdapter` from the client code (it can be `private static` class in the wrapper class) for better readability.

2) An option from the standard jdk libraries is to use [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit
>   comparator is provided) must be consistent with `equals` if it is to
>   correctly implement the `Set` interface. (See `Comparable` or
>   `Comparator` for a precise definition of consistent with `equals`.)
>   This is so because the `Set` interface is defined in terms of the
>   `equals` operation, **but a `TreeSet` instance performs all element
>   comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two
>   elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint
>   of the set, equal.** The behavior of a set is well-defined even if its
>   ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the
>   general contract of the Set interface.

Because `TreeSet` does not rely on `equals`, just implement the proper comparator in the same fashion you implemented `MyAdapter.equals` (to return `0` if `a1.getA() == a2.getA()`);